# Logging specific request header using spring security events

Tags: grails, spring-security

In my grails application, failed login attemps get logged using spring security events as shown here  http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/single.html#7.3%20Registering%20Callback%20Closures

My issue has to do with client ip retrieval. Normally, calling **getRemoteAddress** from details object of the event should do the job, but my case is that my application is behind a reverse proxy therefore i should get the ip from request header **X-Forwarded-For**.

Neither event object nor application context parameters of the closuse provide access to the request object. The global request object isn't available either.

Any ideas how to get access to headers or any other way to implement this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it from `RequestContextHolder`, if it exists:

```
GrailsWebRequest request = RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()
request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For")
```

Generally, as you probably know, it isn't considered a very good idea to access the web session from within Services. First of all, you break the abstraction and separation of service logic, and requests might not always be available or associated with the current thread. One way to access the session from a service is to encapsulate the HTTP session in the following manner:

```
class WebUtilService {
    void withSession (Closure closure) {
        try {
            GrailsWebRequest request = RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()
            GrailsHttpSession session = request.session
            closure.call(session)
        }
        catch (IllegalStateException ise) {
            log.warn ("No WebRequest available!")
        }
    }
}
```

and you would use it like this:

```
class MyService {
    WebUtilService webUtilService

    void doSomething() {
        webUtilService.withSession { HttpSession session ->
            log.info(session.myValue)
            session.newValue = 'Possible, but should be exceptional'
        }
    }
}
```

where you could have access to the `getHeader()` method.

Disclaimer: the code is from Marc-Oliver Scheele's [blog](http://www.mosbase.com/2011/07/grails-accessing-http-session-from.html).

Comment: GrailsWebRequest request = RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes() works! Thanx a lot