# add Request/header data to grails log

Tags: grails

How do I log the `X-Forwarded-For` header using a custom log format in Grails's `Config.groovy`?

There are some [hints about how to do it in other places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870233/logging-specific-request-header-using-spring-security-events), but how do I get data that isn't bound at Config time? I know that Config has access to `grailsApplication`, but it doesn't have access to the `request` data (right?).

My gut reaction is that a [grails filter](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#filters) may be the answer. I'm having trouble finding examples of someone who has done it, and it seems like a common issue. Or is [Burt's 2011 solution](http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=521) ([via](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413057/how-to-systematically-add-decorate-some-data-to-log)) close to what I need?

Realistically I just want to modify the default "apache style" log format and replace the IP with the XFF version if I have one. [This is how I'd do it outside of Grails](http://www.techstacks.com/howto/log-client-ip-and-xforwardedfor-ip-in-apache.html), but that's not what I'm after.

Comment: Just for the assumption.
If you know the concrete class/interface that you want to log, then you can specify it on Config.groovy.
Also you may need to write some handler (which will replace and write your custom log) for logger, but that is need to search in the google.

Comment: Also you may write external utility and rewrite logs by the cron events